# Harmonic oscillator in pertubation theory-cosmology

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

I have a doubt at the following point, in the book "the primordial density pertubation-David H. Lith, Andrew R. Liddle" on page 383, it does that: $$\delta \ddot{\phi}_{k} + 3H\delta \dot{\phi}_{k} + \left(\dfrac{k}{a} \right)^2 \delta \phi_{k} = 0$$

Become a harmonic oscillator: $$\dfrac{d^2 \varphi_k (\eta)}{d \eta^2} + \omega^2_k (\eta) \varphi_k (\eta)=0$$

With $$\omega^2_k = k^2 - \dfrac{2}{\eta^2} = k^2 - 2(aH_k)^2.$$

But I just can't get to that oscillator, even doing $\eta = -1/aH$ and $\varphi = a\delta\phi$. Can anyone help me see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are the dots in the first equation derivatives wrt FRW time or conformal time?

Answer (score 0):

The equation
$$
\ddot \phi+ 2\gamma \dot \phi +(\Omega^2+\gamma^2) \phi=0
$$
has solution
$$
e^{-\gamma t}\sin (\Omega t),
$$
so the damping does influence the frequency along the lines of his equation. Perhaps he is not interested in the exponential decay factor?  This does not account for the factor 3 in the $3H$ though. Is the time dependece of $H$ important in these effects?

Answer (score 0):

with

$$\eta=\int \frac{dt}{a(\eta)}\quad,
\frac{d\eta}{dt}=\frac{1}{a(\eta)}$$

you obtain

$$\dot\varphi\mapsto\frac{d\varphi}{d\eta}\frac{d\eta}{dt}={\frac {{\frac {d}{d\eta}}\varphi  \left( \eta \right) }{a \left( \eta
 \right) }}$$
$$\ddot\varphi\mapsto\left( {\frac {{\frac {d^{2}}{d{\eta}^{2}}}\varphi  \left( \eta
 \right) }{a \left( \eta \right) }}-{\frac { \left( {\frac {d}{d\eta}}
\varphi  \left( \eta \right)  \right) {\frac {d}{d\eta}}a \left( \eta
 \right) }{ \left( a \left( \eta \right)  \right) ^{2}}} \right) 
 \left( a \left( \eta \right)  \right) ^{-1}
$$

$$\ddot\varphi+3\,H\dot\varphi+\left(\frac{k}{a(\eta)}\right)^2\,\varphi(\eta)=0\tag 1$$

where
$$H=\frac{\dot a}{a}=\frac{\frac{da}{d\eta}}{a^2(\eta)}
$$
thus equation (1)

$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\eta}^{2}}}\varphi  \left( \eta \right) +2\,{\frac {
 \left( {\frac {d}{d\eta}}\varphi  \left( \eta \right)  \right) {
\frac {d}{d\eta}}a \left( \eta \right) }{a \left( \eta \right) }}+{k}^
{2}\varphi  \left( \eta \right) 
$$

but this is not your equation ?

Comment: But why does this 2 appear instead of the 3?